# Regex to split words

Tags: c#, regex

I need the following to be split up line by line:

Example:

```
word "multiple set" another word L&D "another set"
```

Output:

```
word
multiple set
another
word
L&D
another set
```

I am currently using:

```
(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)
```

But it does not work with the ampersand (&)

Thanks!

Comment: using C# at the moment

Comment: ...then why don't you just use `\S` instead of word characters? I don't know why you would expect "word character" to match ampersand...

Comment: Have you tried escaping the ampersand?

Comment: You might consider `/\s*(\S+|"[^"]*")\s*/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `"(.*?)"|(\S+)`

This will lazily match any characters in between quotes `OR` any set of non-whitepace characters.

Example [here](http://regex101.com/r/rV5qH8).  Depending on the language you may need to escape your double quotes (`\"(.*?)\"`).

Like @abiessu mentions, you can replace the lazy selector `(.*?)` with a more specific `([^"]*)` selector.  The lazy selector will select everything up until the first character after the selector (the following `"`) where as the more specific `([^"]*)` will select everything asides from `"`.  Not sure if there is a performance difference with lazy selectors vs. character classes, but its up to you.

Comment: Added the option, @abiessu.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern you pass to [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains a capture group, the captured text will be included in the result set. For example:

```
var input = "word \"multiple set\" another word L&D \"another set\"";
var output = Regex.Split(input, "\"([^\"]*)\"|\\s");
```

Produces a result set like this:

```
"word"
""
"multiple set"
""
"another"
"word"
"L&D"
""
"another set" 
""
```

Now, if you just remove the empty elements (a little Linq can be useful here):

```
var output = Regex.Split(input, "\"([^\"]*)\"|\\s").Where(x => x.Length > 0);
```

Produces a result set like this:

```
"word"
"multiple set"
"another"
"word" 
"L&D"
"another set"
```